# Brackets within array

Tags: arrays, c

In the source code for the xv6 operating system, there is the following array declaration:

```
static uint64 (*syscalls[])(void) = {
[SYS_fork]    sys_fork,
[SYS_exit]    sys_exit,
[SYS_wait]    sys_wait,
...
};
```

What values in the brackets are macros defined in a header file, but what do the brackets here mean?

Comment: @Exampleperson It's an array of function pointers (to functions of type `uint64(void)`).

Comment: Note that the standard C syntax requires `=` after the square brackets, e.g. `[SYS_fork] = sys_fork,`. GCC allows the `=` to be omitted because it used that syntax before the proper syntax was standardized by C99.

Comment: @IanAbbott I wonder why they did not adopt this syntax. It is unambiguous and looks cleaner. Could be opinionated though

Comment: @EugeneSh. I suppose it was for consistency with structure member designations.